# grails criteria eq not working

Tags: hibernate, grails, createcriteria

I have problem with criteria in grails

I have a domain User and another domain Conversation
Conversation has Many Participants(domain)

When I do like this:

```
def c = Conversation.createCriteria();
        c.get{
            createAlias('participants', 'p')
            eq 'p.user', user
            eq 'p.folder', folder
            eq 'p.unread', true
            projections{
                count('id')
            }
        }
```

It gives wrong output by showing the following criteria failure :

```
abc.Conversation : 1
    eq('[XYZ]', 'XYZ') == false

    sorry
conv == []
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

the standard way to look through `hasMany` in `criteria` is this:

```
def c = Conversation.withCriteria{
          participants{
            eq 'user', user
            eq 'folder', folder
            eq 'unread', true
          }
          ....
 }
```

Comment: It is also not working..returning empty list. I have tried this one already

Comment: are you sure, you have matching data in your tables?